# Can Mongoose middleware populate then sort an array of references?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-middleware

I'm trying to sort an internal array of document references in a document by the values in the referenced documents.  I'd like to do this every time I run a query so if I can do this with a query sort() function or a post-find middleware that would be ideal (rather than having the code that calls the find needing to sort after the fact).

I have a schema for a ***ModSet*** that looks like this:

```
{
    // details excluded...

    categories:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Category"
    }]
}
```

The ***Category*** schema looks like this (irrelevant details excluded):

```
{
    // details excluded...

    name: {type:String, required:true},
    sortOrder: Number
}
```

I would like to make a find query for a *ModSet* and as part of the query, it should always sort the *categories* array by the *sortOrder* in the populated *Category* document.

As an example, today I run a find and populate query and get the following document back:

```
{
    categories: [
        {name: "categoryA", sortOrder: "5"},
        {name: "categoryB", sortOrder: "3"},
        {name: "categoryC", sortOrder: "1"},
        {name: "categoryD", sortOrder: "4"},
        {name: "categoryE", sortOrder: "2"}
    ]
}
```

What I want to get back is (sorted by categories.sortOrder):

```
{
    categories: [
        {name: "categoryC", sortOrder: "1"},
        {name: "categoryE", sortOrder: "2"},
        {name: "categoryB", sortOrder: "3"},
        {name: "categoryD", sortOrder: "4"},
        {name: "categoryA", sortOrder: "5"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following way.

```
User.find({})
  .populate('categories', 'name sortOrder', null, { sort: { 'sortOrder': -1 } })
```